# Any ideas why I'm getting these errors in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, external, livecode

I have the following errors in xcode below, any ideas what's causing these?

```
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2: /Users/<foldername>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libbtexternal.a: No such file or directory
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2: /Users/<foldername>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libbtexternal.a: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/1x/_btz9s41381cdzz41ty0r5fm0000gn/T//cc8KPWhc.out
error: linking step of external dylib build failed, probably due to missing framework or library references - check the contents of the btexternal.ios file
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Comment: It says itself in the error that your file `libbtexternal.a` is missing..   

If they are showing in your project files try removing them and readding them.

Comment: How do we add it back? In xcode, libbtexternal.a is under Products but it is red and can't be open in finder.

Comment: its red means that it is not added in project.. so for that u click on it press delete and delete file, and then add again from where ever you got it.

Comment: If is red, it means that the file was removed from the disk or the Xcode can't find it at the previously specified path, so copy it again to the path of the group in which it appears red.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find the libbtexternal.a file. Tried to search in spotlight and I don't have it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that are you having the file **libbtexternal.a**. If not then add it to your project after this go to the project and there is option **Build phases**. You find here four rows in which you have to select  **Link Binary with Libraries**  and add your .a file to the frameworks you are seeing here. I think it will work, If not then tell me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find the libbtexternal.a file from my system, is there another way where in I can create another one?

Comment: No it a framework file you can't create. BTW tell me you are making your project by own or you have imported some files from another project to your project.

Comment: I just took this over from other programmer and no longer have connection with him.

Comment: So there would be a file name libbtexternal.a. Without it you should remove all the references of that file from your project. And implement the functionality from your own to work exactly in same way as you want